# What's the expected number of empty boxes if we place k distinguishable balls into n distinguishable boxes?

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics

Harvard Statistics 110: see #30, p. 30 of  [pdf](https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/files/stat110/files/selected_solutions_blitzstein_hwang_probability_01.pdf)

> Randomly, k distinguishable balls are placed into n distinguishable boxes, with all possibilities equally likely. Find the expected number of empty boxes.

[image]

I'm not convinced by the solution because, as illustrated by the picture of balls and boxes, there are $n^k$ different ways of filling the boxes by the balls, and there are $k$ different ways of one box being filled. One box can be filled by $1, 2, \dots k$ balls. Then, $P(I_j=0)=k/n^k$, and $P(I_j=1)=1-k/n^k$. But this will give weird results for $n=9, k=13$. I don't know but I feel there's something missing. May someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flaw in your reasoning is that there are many more than $k$ ways for a particular box to be filled.

Take the concrete example of $n=2$ boxes and $k=3$ balls. You are correct that there are $n^k=8$ different ways to fill the boxes. These $8$ ways can be enumerated by specifying the box where ball 1 lands, the box where ball 2 lands, and the box where ball 3 lands as a vector of three slots. The possibilities are: $$(1,1,1), (2,1,1), (1,2,1), (1,1,2), (2,2,1), (2,1,2), (1,2,2), (2,2,2).$$ Read $(1,1,1)$ as: "ball 1 lands in box 1, ball 2 lands in box 1, ball 3 lands in box 1". Let's focus on how box 1 can be filled or not filled. By inspection we see that there are $7$ ways for box 1 to be filled, not $3$, and in only one of these possibilities is box 1 empty.  Moreover, $1 = (2-1)^3=(n-1)^k$; that is, the only way box 1 can be empty is if each ball lands in a box other than 1, which means each slot in the $3$-vector can be filled only with one of  $n-1$ choices.

Answer (score 1):

Consider there are k balls marked `1,2,3,4,.....k`

and boxes marked as `1,2.....n`

So to find the ways in which balls can be filled can be calculated as

1. When box 1 is filled with **1 ball**. The no of ways in which this can happen is by **choosing 1 ball out of k balls and then each remaining k-1 balls will have n-1 choices to go into n-1 boxes** = $ \binom{k}{1}*(n-1)^{k-1}$
2. When box 1 is filled with **2 balls**. The no of ways in which this can happen is by **choosing 2 ball out of k balls and then each remaining  k-2 balls will have n-1 choices to go into n-1 boxes** = $ \binom{k}{2}*(n-1)^{k-2}$ 
   ......... and so on.
3. till $ \binom{k}{k}*(n-1)^{k-k}$

Total no of ways to be filled = $\binom{k}{1}*(n-1)^{k-1} + \binom{k}{2}*(n-1)^{k-2} ..... + \binom{k}{k}*(n-1)^{k-k}$

$ = [\binom{k}{1}*(n-1)^{k-1} + \binom{k}{2}*(n-1)^{k-2} ..... + \binom{k}{k}*(n-1)^{k-k} + \binom{k}{0}*(n-1)^{k-0}] - \binom{k}{0}*(n-1)^{k-0}$

$ = (1+(n-1))^k - \binom{k}{0}*(n-1)^{k-0}$

$ = n^k - (n-1)^k$